# Django 3 'User' object has no attribute 'admin'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

**SITUATION**

- I am modifying this [GitHub](https://github.com/divanov11/crash-course-CRM/tree/Part-22-S3-File-storage) project from this [YouTube Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inQyZ7zFMHM&list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO&index=22) and this is a [demo](https://dennisivy-crm.herokuapp.com/) how the original application runs.
- My goal is to add settings option for Merchant(in the code Admin or AdminUser) accounts in the marketplace, because in the original project only buyers have the option to add image and their contact details.

**CODE**

model.py

```
#database table create
class Customer(models.Model):
    #empty fields accept - null=True
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default="profile1.png", null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    #show customer name in admin panel
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Adminuser(models.Model):
    #empty fields accept - null=True
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default="profile1.png", null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    #show customer name in admin panel
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('customer/<str:pk_test>/', views.customer, name="customer"),
    path('adminuser/<str:pk_test>/', views.adminuser, name="adminuser"),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
#CUSTOMER_ONLY PROFILE SETTINGS
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def accountSettings(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/account_settings.html', context)



#ADMIN_ONLY PROFILE SETTINGS
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def adminSettings(request):
    admin = request.user.admin
    form = AdminForm(instance=admin)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AdminForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=admin)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/account_admin_settings.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

from .models import *

class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']

class AdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Adminuser
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

navbar.html

```
...
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'adminsettings' %}">SettingsAdmin</a>
</li>
...
```

account_admin_settings.html

```
{%  extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<style>
    .profile-pic{
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height:200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>
<!-- -->
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}"> &#8592; Back to Profile</a>
            <hr>
            <h3 style="text-align: center">Account Settings</h3>
            <hr>
            <img class="profile-pic" src="{{request.user.customer.profile_pic.url}}" >

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="card card-body">

            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Update Information">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ERROR**

```
AttributeError at /accounts/adminsettings/
'User' object has no attribute 'admin'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/adminsettings/
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'admin'
Exception Location: /Users/computer/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py in inner, line 225
Python Executable:  /Users/computer/ven/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/computer/project',
 '/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/computer/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 17 Jun 2020 22:17:12 +0000
```

**TRIED SOLUTIONS**

- My error is not at the login and I am not sure where it is - [Attribute error: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_admin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862889/attribute-error-user-object-has-no-attribute-is-admin)
- I have done migration and make migration before - [Django - No such table: main.auth_user__old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old)
- buyers can access the settings with their own model so this self. does not solves my case [django 'User' object has no attribute 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573999/django-user-object-has-no-attribute-user)
- I don't write over a .save method - ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'user' Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388335/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-user-django)
- It should have the same lvl of instances like in the customer model it is just a different user priority lvl group - [Django 'User' object has no attribute 'Goals'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432643/django-user-object-has-no-attribute-goals)
- This is python 2.7 and Django 1.5 outdated question and answer to begin with - [Django Admin Issue - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212320/django-admin-issue-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-user)
- This has nothing to to do with my case - [Django Admin Action: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708111/django-admin-action-queryset-object-has-no-attribute-user)
- All my middle wears functioning fine - [Django admin error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100144/django-admin-error-wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user)
- Outdated Q & A and my middle wears works - ['WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949198/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user-django-admin)
- `@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])` change to `@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer','admin'])` to have everything in to 1 function in `def accountSettings(request):` gives error
- added `user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='admin')`

  - ERROR: `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/adminsettings/ User has no admin.`
- After I have added `request.user.adminuser` to the view function

  - ERROR `AttributeError at /accounts/adminsettings/ 'User' object has no attribute 'adminuser'`
- Where do I need to use this [How do you catch this exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270042/how-do-you-catch-this-exception/42821464#42821464) in the view or in the model? And How? :

```
MY FUNCTION ANME  
    try:
        # MY ORIGINAL CODE
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # and what goes here?????
```

- @xyres updated view.py def adminSettings(request):

```
#ADMIN_ONLY PROFILE SETTINGS ''' '''
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin'])
def adminSettings(request):
    try:
        admin = requset.user.admin
        form = AdminForm(instance=admin)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AdminForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=admin)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/account_admin_settings.html', context)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print("Either the entry or blog doesn't exist.")
        return render(request, 'accounts/account_admin_settings.html', context)
```

- ERROR: `File "/Users/computer/project/accounts/views.py", line 106
  form = AdminForm(instance=admin)
                                 ^`

  - Hanged back the views.py and models.py back to it's original state and now I get a new error (after makemigration migrate changes)

```
NameError at /accounts/adminsettings/
name 'requset' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`OneToOneField`'s documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField):

> If you do not specify the `related_name` argument for the `OneToOneField`, Django will use the lowercase name of the current model as default value.

So, you'll have to access the related `Adminuser` instance as:

```
request.user.adminuser
```

---

If you want to access it using just `admin`, as mentioned in the docs, you'll have to make use of the `related_name` argument:

```
class Adminuser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='admin' ...)
    ...

# request.user.admin will work now
```

---

### Update

`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` exception is raised when the related object doesn't exist in the database (this is often the case when related field can be `null`). Since there's no `AttributeError` this time, that means Django *did* recognise the `admin` attribute; so, that issue is fixed.

You'll have to handle `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` exception everywhere you're accessing the related attribute.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    admin = requset.user.admin
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    admin = # set some other value ...
```

Comment: I have done to correction and added your code part to the model function but I still get the error see at "TRIED SOLUTIONS".

Comment: I have added both ```request.user.adminuser```  AND ```user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='admin' ...)``` and applied migrarionas in 2 step after both things in my codebase.

Comment: @sogu So the `AttributeError` has been solved. `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` exception is raised when the related object doesn't exist. In this case, there's no related `admin` instance in the database. Handle this exception using `ObjectDoesNotExist` as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get

Comment: @sogu Or here's a better example to handle this exception: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42821464/1925257

Comment: Added question the  stackoverflow.com/a/42821464/1925257 post usage to the "Tried Solutions"

Comment: Updated my post in the "Tried Solutions" the views.py function is not working in it's current condition

Comment: @sogu As I see it, your original issue was solved. Please open a new question for other issues. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223

Comment: Ok. I will do open a new one.